# I get an error when creating a timer

Tags: angular, typescript, timer

Code is below:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {SimpleTimer} from 'ng2-simple-timer';

@Component({
'selector': 'my-app',
'template': `
    <p>
    ng2-simple-timer is available in
      <a href="https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-simple-timer">npm</a> and 
  <a href="https://github.com/J-Siu/ng2-simple-timer">github</a>.
This example is available in
  <a href="https://github.com/J-Siu/ng2-simple-timer-example">github</a>.
</p>
    <div style="border: 1px solid;margin:5px;padding:5px">
    <h3>{{title}}</h3>
    <div>{{counter0}}</div>


</div>`
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
title = 'Angular2 Simple Timer Service Example';

counter0 = 0;
timer0Id: string;
timer0button = 'Subscribe';


// Define SimpleTimer as 'st'
constructor(private st: SimpleTimer) { }

ngOnInit() {
    this.st.newTimer('1sec',1);
    this.subscribeTimer0();

}



subscribeTimer0() {
    if (this.timer0Id) {
        // Unsubscribe if timer Id is defined
        this.st.unsubscribe(this.timer0Id);
        this.timer0Id = undefined;
        this.timer0button = 'Subscribe';
        console.log('timer 0 Unsubscribed.');
    } else {
        // Subscribe if timer Id is undefined
        this.timer0Id = this.st.subscribe('1sec', e => this.timer0callback());
        this.timer0button = 'Unsubscribe';
        console.log('timer 0 Subscribed.');
    }
    console.log(this.st.getSubscription());
}



timer0callback() {
    this.counter0++;
}


}
```

I am trying to learn timer. I found this code on Internet. I installed ng2-simple-timer. But I am getting an error.
The error is in the

```
 this.timer0Id = this.st.subscribe('1sec', e => this.timer0callback());
```

The definition of the error: argument of type '(e:any)=>any' is not assignable to parameter  of type'()=>void.
What is that? Why am i getting this error?

Comment: Are you sure your callback takes in a parameter? Maybe it has to be `() => this.timer0callback()` instead of `e => this.timer0callback()`?

Comment: try `e => { this.timer0callback() } );`

Comment: @FrankModica it is working, thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the type definition thinks your callback shouldn't take a parameter. Try this:

```
this.timer0Id = this.st.subscribe('1sec', () => this.timer0callback());
```